# Залить дамп sql без phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как можно залить дамп sql созданный в phpmyadmin без использования phpmyadmin

Вся проблема в размере дампа и времени его выполнения

например такой маленький дамп в 300 мб а есть еще больше

есть ли инструментик который без ошибок зальет, всякие там тунели не доверяю им

Comment: Adminer пробовали?
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adminer

Comment: А операционная система какая? Имеется ли вообще доступ так к таковой или речь идет о хостинге?

Comment: centos root доступ

Answer (score 4):

Я так делал на линуксе:

```
mysql -u root -p < ~/dumpname.sql
```

Comment: один из самых быстрых и правильных вариантов!

Answer (score 2):

Из mysql консоли, должно работать на ура с большими дампами:

```
mysql> use DATABASE_NAME;

mysql> source path/to/file.sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с БД рекомендую [SQLYog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog)